# Should this be equal to Gamma function or not?

Tags: functions, special-functions

I define the following function:

```
Nat2[s_] := InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[1/t, t, w] (-I w)^(s - 1), 
w, x]/Cos[Pi (s - 1)] /. x -> 1
```

I expected it to always give the same as `Gamma[x]` but it gives some values at negative integers as well. How should I interpret this? Does it mean that embeeded Gamma is poorly realized and should be artificially extended to cover broader range of arguments?

Comment: It's all fine! In[49]:= $Version

Out[49]= "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)" 

In[48]:= InverseFourierTransform[
   FourierTransform[1/t, t, w] (-I w)^(s - 1), w, x]/
  Cos[Pi (s - 1)] /. x -> 1

Out[48]= -Cos[\[Pi] s] Gamma[s] Sec[\[Pi] (-1 + s)] In[53]:= Simplify[%]

Out[53]= Gamma[s]

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze have u tried to feed negative integers to the Nat2 function?

Comment: @ Anixx: The function Gamma[s] has simple poles at the integers <=0. I suggest you read about the properties of the Gamma function in the Help section which also includes a Plot for illustration.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze and what?